# Conditionally Presetting Checkboxes on VBA Userform

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform

I need a Userform to call another Userform that fills text boxes and checkboxes that reads from approx 10 cells from workbook. Basically it is recalling properties of a product that the user can edit, some are text based and some are yes/no (true/false). How do I connect those Userform properties?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Userforms like a class, and declare and instantiate them with New UserFormName. However, they're also a class that always has an instance in the workbook, that you can treat as though it were already declared with New. If you want to pull live information that is already inside it, you'll want to use that one.

For example, if the userform is called "Bacon", and contains some methods that do what you want(Solve_Everything_Click), and some internal data that has the information you need declared at the top(Public MyName As String, TheAnswer As Boolean), you can call it from another sub/function, in userform or out, as long as the code is in the same workbook, or references the book with the userform.

You can access the global instance of it, in the same workbook, by using its name, and accessing the things inside of it with ., keep an eye on the context help that comes up when you press ., which will tell you other methods and variables you might pull from it.

```
Sub PokeAtIt()
    Bacon.TheAnswer = True
    MsgBox Bacon.MyName & " Has the answer: " & Bacon.TheAnswer
    Bacon.Solve_Everything
End Sub
```